# Set the navigation bar background color ios6

Tags: ios6

I used  `[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:color];` to change the navigation bar background color in **iOS7** but not working in **iOS6**.

Comment: this solve the problem `  [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[[UIImage alloc] init] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
            [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundColor:color];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this for IOS 6:

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[[UIImage alloc] init] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundColor:color];
```